# How to collect values from different views

Tags: ios, swiftui

(Sorry for my bad English)
I have in the main ContentView different views. Every view has a value selected.
This is a part of my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 4){
            HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 2){
                PinPosition()
                Spacer()
                UsedClub()
                Spacer()
                Gir()
            }
            ...
            Button(action: {
                    ** How to get the values from views **        
            }){
                Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.down").foregroundColor(.green)
            }
```

When the user press the Save Button, in the action Button, I need get the values returned from every view (PinPosition, UsedClub, Gir).

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You should not work with views in that way, instead operate with data/model and make view only present related data.

Comment: ok, thanks, but how do I do it if I first need to select the values of the views and then store them?
Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I'll put it another way. My ContentView is made up of several sub-views. As the last element of the main ContentView I have the save button. I need to know what value each of the sub-views has (or returns) so that, when pressing the save button, those values are saved.
The sub-views are of the Button, Picker and Toggle type.

Thank you so much for everything.